# program with connecting to sql server in my website with a lots of request

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have website with lots of request and my database connection class has problem
in the request the program when connecting to database another request come and system error.
my class is here

```
    cmd=new SqlCommand();
    con=new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmdLog = new SqlCommand();
    string cns = "";
    if(MABP.GetdomainUrl()=="localhost")
    {
        cns=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringClient"].ToString();
    } else
    {
        cns=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringServer"].ToString();
    }
    con.ConnectionString=cns;
    cmd.Connection=con;
    cmdLog.Connection=con;
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand=cmd;
        while(con.State==ConnectionState.Connecting)
        {
        }
        if(ConnectionState.Open!=con.State)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        da.Fill(dt);
        while(con.State==ConnectionState.Connecting)
        {
        }
        if(ConnectionState.Closed!=con.State)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return dt;
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

i hope you can help me

Comment: Can you put up the error message that you are getting ?

Comment: for example
**The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting. execute GetConfigurationItem 3**

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` opens the connection if it was closed execute and close it. If it was open, execute and leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
            string sql = "select ....";
            string whereToConnect = MABP.GetdomainUrl()=="localhost" ? "ConnectionStringClient" : "ConnectionStringServer";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[whereToConnect].ToString();
            var dt = new DataTable();

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch
                    { 
                        // Deal with exceprion if you want 
                    }
                }
            }

            return dt;
```

Comment: some where i read for security reason we should close connection
is that true?

Comment: @mpourbafrani It is best to close the connection for not consuming resources. Using `using` the connection will both be closed AND disposed when out of scope. Read mode about [DbDataAdapter.Fill Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here. Especially the **Remarks** section.

Comment: thank you my friend i did this but still i have problem too